# SendSmsMessageAsync Example?

Tags: c#, nuget, twilio

I'm confused.  I downloaded the TwilioRestClient using NuGet and there is no `SendMessage` method as described here...

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages

I do see a method called `SendSmsMessageAsyc()` - But I'm not sure if the documentation is outdated or if my NuGet package is outdated.  If the documentation is outdated, can you please point me to an example that uses `SendSmsMessageAsyc()`?

Comment: What's the package id and version? I checked out the stable `Twilio` (v3.6.27) and it was fine. I noticed there is a prerelease version (v3.8.40-beta) and that one has the async calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you grabbed a prerelease version that seems to have changed the api to use all asynchronous calls.  Use the stable version instead.

Package ID: `Twilio`
Stable: v3.6.27
Prerelease: v3.8.40-beta

Then you can follow the examples found there.  If you want to use the async calls in the prerelease version, refer to other tutorials on how to use `async`/`await`.  A method call would look something like this:

```
public async void SendMessageAsync(string from, string to, string body, string[] mediaUrls)
{
    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
    var message = await twilio.SendMessageAsync(from, to, body, mediaUrls);
    if (message.RestException != null) {
        Console.Writeline(message.RestException.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
}
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks a lot!  I got the info on how to install from this page https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp - thanks for setting me straight.  Do you happen to know how I can get an error message when the account SID is wrong, or the from number isn't right, etc?

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  I updated Jeffs example to show how you check for  Authentication and API errors.

Comment: @TheJonz: I can't speak for the library, I can't say that I have used it but you should be able to find all the information you would need in the API documentation. Devin was kind enough to update my answer to show how that can be done.